# Animator работает с процентами в XML?

Tags: анимация

Я так понял, что valueFrom и valueTo работают с конкретными размерами экрана телефона. Можно ли как то работать с процентами?

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="500"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```